# Style based on StaticResource previously defined is not found at runtime

Tags: wpf, telerik, rad-controls

I'm using Telerik's RadControls for WPF with implicit styling. The following style is defined in `Themes/Windows8/Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="telerikRibbonView:RadRibbonView" x:Key="RadRibbonViewStyle">
...
</Style>
```

My own styles and the Telerik default ones get merged like this in the assembly `Lib.Windows.Controls` in the folder `Themes`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Windows8/Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.xaml" />        
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyTheme/TelerikCustomizations.xaml" />

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- avoid optimization -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in `TelerikCustomizations.xaml` I define the following (empty, for testing purposes) style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyThemeRadRibbonViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadRibbonView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RadRibbonViewStyle}" />
```

Which results in the following exception at runtime:

`'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '42'.
{"Cannot find resource named 'RadRibbonViewStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive."}`

Which led me to the following debugging statements in MyView.xaml.cs:

```
public ShellView()
{
    var baseStyle = FindResource("RadRibbonViewStyle");
    var inherited = FindResource("MyThemeRadRibbonViewStyle");
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Now the thing is: The exception is thrown on the second `FindResource` call. With the exact same message. However the `RadRibbonViewStyle` is clearly found in the first line of the constructor.

If it matters, the merged dictionary is actually merged in App.xaml a second time.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="TestClient.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Views/ShellView.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Lib.Windows.Controls;component/Themes/MyTheme.xaml" />

              <ResourceDictionary>
                    <!-- added to avoid optimization -->
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`App.xaml.cs` does not overwrite the constructor. In fact it does not do anything.

**Update**

If I merge the Telerik dictionaries in `TelerikCustomizations.xaml` instead of merging them in yet another dictionary (`MyTheme.xaml`), the exception disappears.

However, I'd still like to know why this happens.

Comment: I think TelerikCustomizations.xaml is not able to find RadRibbonViewStyle in BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RadRibbonViewStyle}"

Comment: Yeah, but why? Themes/Windows8/Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.xaml gets merged in right before TelerikCustomizations.xaml.

Comment: Aren't you missing `Themes` from the source of first resource dictionary?

Comment: @RohitVats no, because the dictionary is in the Themes folder. And I think that would generate a compile time error, not a runtime exception.

Comment: You can try  with `DynamicResource` : `BasedOn="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=RadRibbonViewStyle}"` Or you can merge `RibbonView.xaml` not directly the app.xaml or your merged dictionary but in your `TelerikCustomizations.xaml` and in your app.xaml only refernce `TelerikCustomizations.xaml`. So the point is that `TelerikCustomizations.xaml` and `RibbonView.xaml` should not be "next" to each other in a MergedDictionaries. But your customizations should depend on the ribbon.

Comment: @colinsmith Does not seem to work. Added a style without a key to App.xaml and the dictionary where everything gets merged together. still the same exception.

Comment: @nemesv Merging the Telerik dictionaries in `TelerikCustomizations.xaml` works. I still want to know why though ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to merge in the `Windows8/Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.xaml` in your  `MyTheme/TelerikCustomizations.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Windows8/Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="MyThemeRadRibbonViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadRibbonView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RadRibbonViewStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And now you can use/merge this dictionary wherever you want.

You need to do this because `StaticResource` is not working between "sister"  `MergedDictionaries` so you cannot reference a resource which was merged on the same level because the `StaticResource` looks only backwards to the **direct** parents:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968442.aspx):

> XAML resource references within a particular resource dictionary must
>   reference a resource that has already been defined with a key, and
>   that resource must appear lexically before the resource reference.
>   Forward references cannot be resolved by a XAML resource reference

But when using `MergedDictionaries`:

> In the resource-lookup sequence, a **MergedDictionaries dictionary is
>   checked only after a check of all** the keyed resources of the
>   ResourceDictionary that declared MergedDictionaries.

Comment: So in theory that would also work if you include `Windows8/Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.xaml` in your App.xaml before the `MyTheme.xaml` but I'm not sure in that. From the documentation it is not clear whether `StaticResource` is not working for direct "sister dictionaries" or it is also not working between "sister dictionary branches"...

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains a lot ;)